# How can I clean and convert to float the values of column which has a formula in its last cell

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a data set for shopping orders. I want to clean the  column  name 'total' and convert the values to float for further manipulation. However the last cell of the column has a formula.I want to remove the formula and convert the column to float values like so:

[image]

This is what I have tried to clean the column:

```js
df.total[df.total == 'Grand Total:'] = '0'
df["total"].str.replace(',','').str.replace('Rs.','').str.replace('₹','').astype(float)
df.head(10)
```

Gives the following error:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    895     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    896         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 897         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    898 
    899     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '=SUBTOTAL(109E2:E67)'
```

Comment: please share a sample of the data so we can reproduce

Comment: @Tomar I am new to both analytics and to Stack Overflow and this is my first question.So how should share the sample data with you here?

Comment: edit your question and read it before https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Tomar I got the answer after a few edits myself. Thank you for the help anyway.

Comment: then please consider posting it as an answer to your own question and accept it, so we can see that this problem has been solved